# How can I build my React Native Storybook to web?

Tags: react-native, storybook, react-native-web

I am running [React Native Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/guides/guide-react-native/) which runs Storybook in the Native emulator.

In addition to the how React Native Storybook works currently, I would also like to build an instance of it for web as a reference companion to our app.

I am using `"@storybook/react-native": "5.3.14"`. My stories are located at `./storybook`.

Answer (score 4):

Install `react-native-web`, `@storybook/react` and `babel-plugin-react-native-web` from npm in your project root.

Add a new configuration directory for Storybook, say `./.storybook-website`. Inside this directory, add `main.js`. This creation would otherwise be done by the Storybook installation wizard.

```
my-app
├── .storybook-website
│   └── main.js
└── // .... rest of your app
```

Add the following content to main.js:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../storybook/stories/index.js'],
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...(config.resolve.alias || {}),
      // Transform all direct `react-native` imports to `react-native-web`
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
      // make sure we're rendering output using **web** Storybook not react-native
      '@storybook/react-native': '@storybook/react',
      // plugin-level react-native-web extensions
      'react-native-svg': 'react-native-svg/lib/commonjs/ReactNativeSVG.web',
      // ... 
    };
    // mutate babel-loader
    config.module.rules[0].use[0].options.plugins.push(['react-native-web', { commonjs: true }]);
    // console.dir(config, { depth: null });
    return config;
  },
};
```

Update the `stories` path in main.js to the location of your existing root story.

Finally add run scripts to your package.json:

```
"storybook:web": "start-storybook -p 6006 --config-dir ./.storybook-website",
"storybook-build:web": "build-storybook --config-dir ./.storybook-website --output-dir dist-storybook-website --quiet"
```

Presto! Run using `yarn storybook:web`. This will run storybook dev server, opening a browser showing what you usually would see in the device emulator.

Comment: do you know if this is still valid for the current version of storybook? I haven't found much about how to setup it up for the browser using react-native-web.

Comment: The current version of Storybook for RN is still based on v4 so yes.

Comment: tried to do it in the case of storybook v5+ and it doesn't register my stories at all (Using: 
``` import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react'; ``` ) but nothing works

Comment: "start-storybook" was overwritten for me by @storybook/react-native-server or @storybook/react-native. To solve the storybook:web script I replaced `start-storybook` with `node_modules/@storybook/react/bin/index.js`